# Visual Studio Advanced Installer - Install a Windows Service with build transforms

Tags: visual-studio, windows-services, advanced-installer

I have a .Net 4.7 application which is developed as a windows service. I have an MSI project which does the installation and there is a post install activation script that also gets executed (manually).

I am trying to replicate the old installer using the Advanced Installer Extension in Visual Studio and cant resolve these issues.

The first one is how do I stop Advanced Installer from creating multiple subdirectories in the target installation location.  The install parameters have the Application folder set to  *[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer][ProductName]*  however, I am getting *[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer][ProductName][ProductName]*.  I have the project Output under the Application folder in the files and folders tab.

Secondly, how do I install the application  as a Windows Service.  I can see this in the external version of Advanced Installer when I create a new package, but can't find the settings for the one within Visual Studio for the existing package.

Comment: I use Advanced Installer.   Not for a service so I am sorry I don't have an answer for your question, but have you tried their own forums?  I've gotten good help there.

Answer (score 0):

Within Advanced Installer extension for VS you cannot configure the install location template, nor a service installation. As you already noticed those settings are available only in the desktop version of Advanced Installer.

As a workaround you can use the [Edit in Advanced Installer] button from VS and then edit the install location template from *Install Parameters* view in Advanced Installer desktop app.

Also, while in Advanced Installer desktop app you can configure a service installation as exposed in [this tutorial](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-install-service.html).

Comment: Thanks muchly.  I have version 19.5 of Advanced Installer.  When I open it from Visual Studio (edit in Adv. Inst.), I cannot find the options to configure a service.   If I open Adv. Inst. from the start menu, I can create a new project as a service (under resources there is a services menu - this is missing when I open the desktop version from VS). The desktop version does not appear to work with Visual Studio (when I build a solution I need it to build the package - this will eventually added to a build pipeline).

Comment: Regarding the other issue, I can access the install parameters and remove the [ProductName] reference in the Application folder setting so it reads [ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\. If I don't, I get two nested productName directories after the install.